# Is there any way in Database Rider to reduce duplication of @DataSet configuration properties?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, dbunit

Is there any way in Database Rider to reduce duplication of *@DataSet* configuration properties?

For example, suppose we have:

```
@DataSet(value = "yml/test1.yml", cleanAfter = true, skipCleaningFor = {"zone_code", "product_code", "product_type", "user_type"})
public void test1() {
  //...
}

@DataSet(value = "yml/test2.yml", cleanAfter = true, skipCleaningFor = {"zone_code", "product_code", "product_type", "user_type"})
public void test2() {
  //...
}
```

Here as you can see **cleanAfter** and **skipCleaningFor** are duplicated. And this is just an example. The list of skipCleaningFor can be even longer. Having thousands of tests with the same list of skipped tables is a nightmare. Imagine we need to change this list, in thousands of places.

Extracting this list to some `static final` variable is not an option, because parameters to annotation can be only true inline constants (you will get compilation error).

[Meta datasets](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider#38-meta-datasets) are one of the ways of reducing duplication but they include ALL properties, and it's not possible to override some of the properties (like **value** in my example)

[Merge datasets](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider#39-merge-datasets) looks promising, but not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I figured out how to do it using merging datasets.
First, we need some BaseTest for all our tests with the config of skipCleaningFor :

```
@DataSet(value = "yml/empty.yml", skipCleaningFor = {"zone_code", "product_code", "product_type", "user_type"})
class BaseTest
```

Where empty.yml it's just some empty dataset to avoid error during tests execution.
Then, in the test class, we put

```
@DbUnit(mergeDataSets = true)
@DBRider
class MyTest extends BaseTest {
   @DataSet(value = "yml/test1.yml", cleanAfter = true)
   public void test1() {
     //...
   }

   @DataSet(value = "yml/test2.yml", cleanAfter = true)
   public void test2() {
     //...
   }
```

And that's it - the config is no longer duplicated!